# Cannot delete wired connection

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, wired

I'm trying to delete a wired connection from network manager in Kubuntu Saucy (Converted and upgraded from Lubuntu Raring). It asks me for confirmation, which I give, but the connection doesn't get deleted.
How do I delete this connection? Ubuntu always connects to it automatically instead of preferring the connection I created (which is working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this command:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections 
sudo rm {wired_connection_name}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start the network connection editor as superuser, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and execute this:

```
gksudo nm-connection-editor
```

Now you can edit and delete every connection.